# CSV regex with any digit

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am trying to looking for regex which allows any comma separated values. Like this.

1. `23,23,23`
2. `233-2-3,23,23`
3. `23/23/2333,22-22-2222,23`

I have tried couple of things but nothing fits 100%.

1. `[^,;]+`
2. `/(?!,)(?:(?:,|^)([-+]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+))*$/`
3. `(\d+, ?)+(\d+)?`

My use case is , if my string pass through above regex, I will parse all the values and store it into an array. If string doesn't have any single `,` than leave that string.

thanks

Comment: If you have `23,24,25`, what is the desired output ? Is it `23,24,25` ? or `23` `24` and `25` ?

Comment: the whole string would allow if string has ",". So that would be 23,24,25

Comment: Try the [following](http://regex101.com/r/aF6hR3).

Comment: There is maybe a problem thought it will even match `233-2-3-,23,23`. Is that ok ?

Comment: i have just tried another use case, its allowing any number value as well. I mean if you just enter 23, it allows. btw this is the closest answer i have come across right now. let me find something else.

Comment: Can you come to the [regex chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/) ?

Comment: i think its blocked in my company

Comment: How's that possible if you can surf on SO xD ... Anyways, so you want atleast 2 numbers `23,23` and the numbers is it only `2` and `3` or can you use `1234567890` ?

Comment: I was thinking of another thing now just to check if "," is there in the string.

Comment: I;ve come with a [solution](http://regex101.com/r/uS2vV2) but everything has to be on a seperate line, note the use of the `m` modifier.

Comment: Is the Question Solved? If so please mark somehow. THX. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, we have come to the following solution:

```
(?m)^(?:\d+[\/,-]){2,}\d+$
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?m)` : make `^` and `$` match start and end of line respectively.
- `^` : Start of line
- `(?:` : Ignore group

  - `\d+` : Match a digit 1 or more times
  - `[\/,-]` : Followed by a `/` or `,` or `-`
- `)` : Closing parenthesis for the ignore group
- `{2,}` : Match two times or more
- `\d+` : Match a digit 1 or more times
- `$` : End of line

**[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/uS2vV2)**